# How can I check if Child has border?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to check if Child has has a border that is "solid 2px black" so I only append the Elements that have a border. How can i check that?

I've tried using source.firstChild.style.border == "solid 2px black" but it doesn't work.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/merisbsc/pen/BvMKBp

```
## html ##
  <ul id="source" class="object">
      <li id="eins">Name1</li>
      <li id="zwei">Name2</li>
      <li id="drei">Name3<li>
      <li id="vier">Name4</li>
    </ul>


    <div id="moveToTarget" class="object">
      <button type="button" id="name">--></button>
    </div>
    <div id="moveToSource" class="object">
      <button type="button" id="name">
      <--</button>
    </div>

    <ul id="target" class="object">

    </ul>
## js ##
      function moveToTarget() {
        while (source.hasChildNodes()) {
          target.appendChild(source.firstChild);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Do you have some HTML you can post too?

Comment: Are the styles inline, or applied with CSS/classes?

Comment: styles are with id's and classes

Comment: Can you upload your code on Codepen or something? So we can help you

Comment: If it's a class you have applied, you could check for that. Otherwise the ComputedStyle may be something to look in to: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getcomputedstyle.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for each element in your targeted htmlcollection the one you need from his css param (that what I understand) and then you can do whatever you want with it.

Here how I'd do it

```js
var style;
//make an htmlcollection of your elements
var divz = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

// parse your htmlcollection to find the one!
for (let e of divz) {
style = window.getComputedStyle(e);
 if(style.getPropertyValue('border') == '2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
  console.log(e); //use the "one" as you want 
 }

}
```

```css
#a {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id='a'>


</div>
<div id='b'>


</div>
<div id='c'>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)
- Get the border styles (this was trickier in Firefox as noted in the code below) -- *I tested with Chromium 65 and Firefox 64*
- Compare result to a string of the value you expect.

**Important Notes:**

- Be aware that using CSS named colors will not work so you will have to transpose those to `rgb()` color statements. The separator is a comma as well as a space, so be aware of this, too.
- You will have to modify the following for your specific use-case and existing code, however this hopefully is a strategy similar to what you're after.

[Codepen of the same below](https://codepen.io/seantunwin/pen/QzYKMG)

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.container');
const black = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'; // spaces matter!
const styleToMatch = '2px solid '.concat(black);

/**
 * Get an element's border styles (simplistic)
 * Tested against Chromium 65 and Firefox 64
 * @param HTMLElement el
 * @return string
 **/
function getElementBorderStyles(el) {
  // exit function if not an HTML Element
  if (! el instanceof HTMLElement) {
    console.warn('el is not an HTMLElement');
    return false;    
  }
  
  // Get the Element's Computed Styles
  const styles = getComputedStyle(el);
  
  // Build the string of border styles
  // Firefox needs to build the string as styles.border is likely empty string, otherwise use styles.border (Chromium 65 tested)
  const borderStyles = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') !== -1)
                       ? ''.concat(styles.borderBlockStartWidth
                         ,' ', styles.borderBlockStartStyle
                         , ' ', styles.borderBlockStartColor)
                       : styles.border;  
  
  return borderStyles;
}

/**
 * Simple string match
 * @param string s1
 * @param string s2
 * @return boolean
 **/
function hasBorderStyleMatch(s1, s2) {
  return s1 === s2;
}

// Convert HTMLCollection to Array using spread operator
// Cycle through the elements to detect a border style match
[...parent.children].forEach( el => {
  // Template Literal for our test output
  const rstr = `.${el.classList} Matches Border Style (${styleToMatch}): ${hasBorderStyleMatch(getElementBorderStyles(el), styleToMatch)}`;
  
  // (Optional) Output to page
  parent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<p>${rstr}<p>`);
  
  // Log the same
  console.log(rstr);
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0.2rem;
  font-size: 0.75rem;      
}

div:first-of-type {
  margin: 1rem;  
}

div {
  min-height: 1rem;  
}

.has-border {
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="has-border"></div>
  <div class="no-border"></div>  
</div>
```